# Как выполнить группировку по сменам в Postgree?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица:

```
time|addr|x|y
```

Мне нужно сгруппировать сумму `x` по сменам (по `8` часов). Не получается сделать по сменам. Не понимаю, как записать `group by`.

```
SELECT sum(x), to_char(date_trunc('hour', time), 'hh24:mi') as period
FROM public.trac_path_rmp where time > '2023-03-01 08:00:00.024314' and time < '2023-03-03 18:01:00.024314' 
    group by  period
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какие именно границы у смен? 0-8, 8-16 и 16-24? ну тогда тупо ```GROUP BY date_trunc(date), extract(hour) / 8```. Если нет - сначала вычесть нужное количество часов, чтобы попасть в эти диапазоны.

Comment: Да именно такие смены 0-8, 8-16 и 16-24

Comment: Не пойму как вы предлагаете записать date_trunc?

Comment: Отрезать компоненту времени, оставить только дату. Можно и просто `column :: date`.

Comment: А как это поможет? В сутках 3 смены?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 3 и 5.

Comment: Как уже было указано в первом комментарии  ``date_trunc(date)`` - это номер суток (дата) и ``extract(hour) / 8`` - это номер смены в сутках.